# Saving one or multiple X509Certificates to a PKCS#7 File / Container?

Tags: java, export, x509certificate, pkcs#7

I have multiple X509Certificates. Now I want to save one or more of them into a PKCS#7 File / Container with Java.

I could read in one or more Certificates from a PKCS#7 file, but I don't know how to write them to a PKCS#7 file. I only know that the data in this file is PEM encoded and this data is within the tags `--- BEGINN PKCS7 ---` and `--- END PKCS7 ---`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, read the whole RFC for PKCS#7/CMS for better understanding. Please follow this [RFC link](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5652).

For easy implementation use bouncycastle library. Now, There are different types of PKCS#7.CMS data (like signedData, envelopedData etc.). Lets take, you want to use signeData format. Then, you need to generate [CMSSignedData](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pkixdocs1.4/org/bouncycastle/cms/CMSSignedData.html) data. For that, you need to prepare private key and Certificate chain. Here, I am assuming, you already have those. Now prepare [CMSProcessableByteArray](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pkixdocs1.4/org/bouncycastle/cms/CMSProcessableByteArray.html).

Sample code for CMSProcessableByteArray:

```
CMSProcessableByteArray msg = new CMSProcessableByteArray("Hello World".getBytes());
```

hen declare CMSSignedDataGenerator and add signerInfo and certificates.

```
CMSSignedDataGenerator gen = new CMSSignedDataGenerator();
gen.addSignerInfoGenerator(new JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder(......));
gen.addCertificates(certs);
```

Then generate CMSSignedData with CMSSignedDataGenerator and CMSProcessableByteArray.

```
CMSSignedData cmsData = gen.generate(msg, true);
```

Now, there are two formats for you to write the file in: Pem and Der. You want to write in pem encoded. So then, Take the whole data in a ContentInfo.

```
ContentInfo ci = ContentInfo.getInstance(ASN1Object.fromByteArray(signedData));
```

Now, use Pemwriter to write the contentInfo object in p7b format. Open the file and see user certificates.

```
PEMWriter pemWriter = new PEMWriter(new FileWriter("Demo-CMS.p7b"));
pemWriter.writeObject(obj);
pemWriter.flush();
pemWriter.close();
```